# Не изменить ли текст "Показать действия над этим сообщением"?

Tags: предложение

Под рейтингом каждого (или почти каждого) вопроса и ответа есть пиктограмма часов со стрелкой по кругу. Если навести туда мышь, то появится подсказка "Показать действия над этим сообщением". Для меня эта фраза означает, что мне там покажут действия, которые можно произвести над данным сообщением - поставить оценку/тревогу, редактировать, и т.п. На самом же деле там открывается ИСТОРИЯ действий над сообщением.

Может быть, изменить текст? Например, на "Показать историю сообщения".

PS. В английской версии там написано "Show activity on this post", что не вызывает подобной путаницы.

Comment: А лучше еще проще - *"Показать историю изменений"*. Контекст и так понятен )

Comment: @Kromster Так лучше, конечно. Но там не только изменения, но и комментарии.

Comment: "*Показать историю активности"* ?

Comment: А может просто "История вопроса" ? Без "Показать"?) В https://youtrack.jetbrains.com например просто пишется "Issue History" - "История проблемы"